# Cannot check out documents anymore

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, check-in, check-out, office-integration

Our WSS3 document libraries no longer prompt to check out. I've confirmed check out is required for editing, and I've tried a new library. We're getting the same results. I also check the authentication provider and ensured client integration is enabled. This has been working great for quite some time. Users are using Office 2003. Could there have been a Windows Server update which disabled this for the old Office version?

When attempting to check out the file within SharePoint, using it's resident checkout functionality I get an error

> The file "MyFile.xls" is not checked
>   out.

Comment: Do you mean that they do not get a prompt in Office 2003 anymore to save / checkout as a minor or major version or that no versions are added in SharePoint itself?

Comment: Do you happen to use Citrix? I have seen one case with a client that migrated to Citrix. After that the prompting for check in / check out disappeared.

Comment: Correct, Office doesn't prompt to check out, and there isn't an option to check it out to edit. If they edit it, they have to upload it manually.

Comment: Nope, no Citrix

Comment: Did some more research on the error and discovered there's a hotfix available, then checked the version of the server and it doesn't have a SP installed yet, so we'll try that first.

Comment: News of a hotfix is good! If you find it fixes the issue please come back and leave the details as an answer. If it doesn't, edit this question with what you've tried and your question will bump back on to the home page for other eyes to see.

Comment: Yeah, SP 2 fixed it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the latest service pack resolved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

This could be a client issues.  Try the following if the SP does not work.  Run the Microsoft Office Diagnostic Tool, which is part you the Office installation on a client. This will look for and correct any errors in your Office installation.  When the diagnostic tool is finished try to check out and edit a document. The [David Klein's blog entry](http://ddkonline.blogspot.com/2007/07/issues-with-sharepoint-2007-checkout.html) for additional information.  Read the comment too.